Reverse harem book about a girl whose long-lost friend kidnaps her and brings her to a magic school
I read this book like a year ago and it's been stuck in my head recently, but I just can't find it.
All I remember is that it's a fated mage book and, in the start, the main character is taken to a magic school, but she doesn't know anything about magic and doesn't think she has powers. But as she falls in love with her mates, she starts to take on their powers. I know two of her mates are twins and one has light powers while the other has shadow powers. Another one of her guys is her green magic teacher. And I think, at some point, she summoned a dead witch who had her same power and she learns from her, but I don't know if I'm mixing that in from another book.

Are you using mate here to mean friend or sexual partner?

If someone said the term "reverse harem" to me, I would think it was a story told from the perspective of one of the people in someone else's "harem" (really, the situation in most anime is more like a wish-fulfillment version of polyamory than a harem in terms of sociocultural context, but I guess that is not relevant). Is that the case here?

@terdon - Given that it's a reverse harem (i.e. a female protagonist with a male harem) story, 'mate' would almost certainly refer to a romantic/sexual relationship rather than a platonic friendship.

@LogicDictates yes, but mate implies a long term bond, and seems odd in the context of a harem, and its use for friends in the context of a school is very common  in some dialects, hence the question.

@Tardon they were partners
